# Rewrite declaration so that order no longer matters

Tags: xml, dtd

I have the following DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT moives(moive*, people*)>
<!ELEMENT moive(title, genre, year, cast, director, producer, studio)>
<!ELEMENT title(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT genre(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cast(character+)>
<!ELEMENT director(EMPTY)>
<!ATTLIST director did IDREF #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT producer(EMPTY)>
<!ATTLIST producer pid IDREF #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT studio(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT character (role, name)>
<!ATTLIST character cid IDREF #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT role (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name(first, last)>
<!ELEMENT first(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT last(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT people(name)>
<!ATTLIST people peoid ID #REQUIRED>
```

I want to rewrite the declaration for the element name so that it can have exactly the same content but the order no longer matters. For instance, a name can be first, last or last, first. I am thinking of using `<!ELEMENT name ANY>`, but is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<!ELEMENT name ((first,last)|(last,first))>
```